# How to store Miso

Tags: storage-method, storage-lifetime

Most recipes I see that use miso require rather small amounts.  As I don't want to waste a lot of miso, I would like to know how to store miso long term.  Particularly, I want to know if I can freeze miso, as that seems like it would be the longest term solution.  I don't know if this will damage it, though.  If the fridge or pantry is the best option, how long will it last?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

storing in the fridge works well for me. it lasts indefinitely that way. i've never had the taste go weird, or see it get moldy, or anything like that.

Answer (score 2):

Likewise, I've kept miso in the fridge for 6-12 months before and it has always been fine, likely because it is (when undiluted) rather salty. A few tips:

- A white residue can form on the surface. Just scrape it off - it is still OK.
- If it is in a loose packet, close it with a food clip then put it in a lidded food container. This keeps it fresh, and stops it affecting other foods/absorbing odours. Some liquid can separate from miso after a while; the clip keeps this in.
- If you want an easier option than the above, you can buy miso in a plastic tub with tight-fitting lid.
- Make sure you don't contaminate the miso with anything else. Generally this is easy, but I always measure the amount I need with a fresh spoon, into a small bowl.
- I have never tried freezing miso, but [have read that this is fine](http://chowhound.chow.com/topics/279941), and may keep it even fresher.